# UITableView cell textLabel color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a simple issue with `UITableViewCell`.
What I want is to change the text color of a selected cell.
In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I set:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

If the  `selectionStyle` is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`,  `highlightedTextColor` will not change. 
So I use these two methods to set the text color:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];    
  return indexPath;
}
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
  return indexPath;
}
```

It works, but when scrolling the tableview, the color changes back.

Comment: what about declaring an NSIndexPath *urIndexPath; in your .h? then in your didSelecteRowAtIndexPath method, pass the selected cell's indexPath to urIndexPath then reloadData to update the UI, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, say something like, if urIndexPath is == indexPath {set color to orange; }else{ whatever color is by default}

Comment: @Akhildas When you scroll the tableView cellForRowAtIndex: method will get called always.But not other methods you have.Better you can call "WillSelectRowAtIndexPath" method inside you "cellForRowAtIndex:" method to make it works

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Got the solution
by setting color in  if (cell == nil) check

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

All that you have to do is

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

inside if(cell == nil)

that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

set a global : `int m_selectedCell;`
modify it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

just add

```
if(m_selectedCell == indexPath.row){
...
...
}else{
}
```

in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

that's all !