# How do I control the background color of selected cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` as a preference screen, where rows represent user selections.
I am maintaining the selection using `NSUserDefaults`. My issue is that I am trying to create a special look for the cell, which I do by building a special color and using it in the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return cell;
    }
```

Based on this, when a user click occurs, it displays the grayish color that I am building in this event, which is what I want. When the user deselects it, the greyish background color is gone.

Now I need to add the `NSUserDefaults`, to check whether that cell is already saved. The events becomes this now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:selectedOption]) {
        //Here, how can I make the cell look grayish in the background? 
        //If I do cell.selected = true// the cell shows a black background color 
     }
    return cell;
    }
```

If I call `cell.selected = true` the cell has a black background and not really what I am looking for.
I am at a loss as to where I should perform this customization.

Update :
Following rdelmar's answer I updated the cellForRowAtIndexPath and added the customisation code

```
 if (myArray[indexPath.Row][selectionState] == YES){
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

}else{
cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

}

Still didn;'r resolve the issue, meaning that it would pass the verification l(selectionState == yes, and hit the code to change the color of the background view, but when displaying it would still be unchanged.

I found this method willDisplayCell, and I moved the code about customaisation there, still didn';t work !!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (myArray[indexPath.Row][selectionState] == YES){
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
}
else{
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
return cell;
}
```

Am I supposed to intercept another event or method?

Comment: Please check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733267/uitableview-cell-textlabel-color

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to do this in the user defaults -- if you do, you'll have to somehow keep track of what index in your array (that supplies the data for the cells) a selected cell corresponds to.

I would change the structure of myArray to be an array of dictionaries with two keys, one for the data, and one for the selection state of the cell. You would update the value of the cell state in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, check the value of that cell state key (lets call it selectionState):

```
if (myArray[indexPath.Row][selectionState] == YES){
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}else{
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Of course, you'll have to save the array itself to disk to make the cell state value persistent.

Comment: hi @rdelmar, I updated my answer based on your answer. still not working though.

Comment: @funkycoldmedia, It's probably not working because the cell isn't in the selected state. Maybe try setting the cell's background color instead of setting the background view (and maybe set the cell's selectionStyle to none, so you don't get the blue color on selection).