# Swift Change textColor on Selection

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8.1

How do I change the `textColor` of a `label` or a `cell` on selection in iOS Swift?

I want the background to not to change. Only `textColor` and `seperatorColor` if any. Something like:

```
label.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
```

I have seen this happen in some apps that the color changes. But I cannot get any near to it. According to Apple Dev Reference:

> Subclasses that use labels to implement a type of text button can use
>   the value in this property when drawing the pressed state for the
>   button. This color is applied to the label automatically whenever the
>   highlighted property is set to true.

But, labels compile fine and don't change color on highlight.  Buttons do not have `highlightedTextColor`

Comment: So, what do you have so far?

Comment: @SebastianDressler I did not find any methods in reference to Dev Docs.

Comment: `UILabel` does not support selection, you may want to use `UITextField`. For `UITableCell` there is e.g. [UITableView Cell selected Color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color)

Comment: @SebastianDressler I mentioned `NOT BACKGROUND COLOR`. And I specially need it for `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Alright, then how about [UITableView cell textLabel color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733267/uitableview-cell-textlabel-color). It even shows the approach when to set it. It's Objective-C but easily adaptable IMO.

Comment: @SebastianDressler Does not work in Swift

Comment: What exactly does not work in Swift?

Comment: @SebastianDressler the Code above. It complies fine. Does not give a highlight

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. The code I linked to is Objective-C code, obviously you have to adapt it to your project. The answer by @rakeshbs provides the exact same information but in Swift. I.e. it is not clear, why his code works and the other (after being adopted to Swift) should not work or is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you (use/not use) a custom cell(as xib), you can select the lable, and from utilities, go to highlighted and change the color to the color you want to show in selection. 
and this is a snapshot to be more clear :) 
 [image: snapshot]

Answer (score 8):

I've tried setting it in `didSelectAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectAtIndexPath` but the color was getting changed with a delay. I didn't like that.

This is how I ended up solving the problem:

I have subclassed my `UITableViewCell` and connected all the `@IBOutlet`s. In `awakeFromNib()` I simply did this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()        

    self.myLabel.highlightedTextColor = .blackColor()

}
```

Works perfectly now!

btw this is my first ever answer on stack overflow please be nice to me  hehe

(I'm using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.2.1)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the color in `didSelectAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Dequeue cell
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: plus one for the logic but since I am using navigation bars, the text still remains highlighted when I come back. And also, the performance is very poor. Only highlights when segue starts.

Comment: what do you mean only highlights when segue starts?

Comment: @rakeshbs I think there are some other problems and misunderstandings which we are not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

In the cell itself in the method setSelected you can override it and then provide whatever colour or highlighted state you want:

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

```
    if isSelected {
        // your color or highlited here
    } else {
       // your colour or highlighted here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAt` `indexPath` you can just add this line

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```